# ZF2 Rewrite for Subdirectory / Url Routes

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, zend-framework2

My public folder is within a sub-directory. So I am using two .htaccess files.

The first one outside of the public folder directory is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [NC,QSA]
```

The second one inside the public folder is the default Zend one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

When I go to http://mydomainname.com/myappname I get the following error:

A 404 error occurred

Page not found.

The requested URL could not be matched by routing.

,but this works of course when I go to http://mydomainname.com/myappname/public

I am not sure whether my .htaccess needs to be fixed or if I need to fix my routes

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution would be to move the content of your public folder to its parent directory.

Copy

```
myappname/public/css
myappname/public/images
myappname/public/js
myappname/public/index.php
myappname/public/.htaccess
```

to

```
myappname/css
myappname/images
myappname/js
myappname/index.php
myappname/.htaccess
```

Make sure you replace `myappname/.htaccess` with the default zf2 `public/.htaccess`

Then in `myappname/index.php` comment out:

```
//chdir(dirname(__DIR__));
```